# Does lui have any purpose in "tu peux lui emprunter du lait."

Tags: grammaire, sens, traduction, vocabulaire

> Tu peux lui emprunter du lait.

I feel that *lui* is a bad translation in English if it is translated as a pronominal: *I can borrow him some milk.*

But I am probably wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

*Lui* is an indirect complement here:

> You can borrow milk from him/her.

Comment: How does one distinguish *I can borrow to him...* from *I can borrow from him...* in French? Using a different verb?

Comment: @Roger Vadim: I don't believe *borrow to him* exists in English. Do you mean *borrow for him*?

Comment: @PeterShor probably - you likely know better than me. Would *borrow for him* mean the same as *borrow him* (as in the OP)?

Comment: @Roger Vadim: *borrow a shirt for him* and *borrow him a shirt* (this second construction is not used very much) both would mean *borrow a shirt in order for him to wear it*.

Comment: @PeterShor what I meant is the difference between the giver and the taker: *I borrow a shirt from him.* = He gives me a shirt. Wouldn't *He borrowed a shirt to me.* mean the same thing? Or do we need a different verb in English?

Comment: @roger Vadim: *he **lent** a shirt to me*, or (less common) *he **loaned** a shirt to me*. But you're quite possibly right about what the OP meant by *I can borrow him some milk.*

Comment: @PeterShor interesting - I have only recently encountered the concept of strictly delineating perspective of speaker, interlocutor and a third person while trying to learn Portuguese, but I had never given it much attention in English. Here is a related post that I ran into today: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/9062/11666 (especially the first answer)

Comment: @Roger Vadim: They have different verbs for them in French, too. *You can **lend** him milk* would be *tu peux lui **prêter** du lait.*

Comment: @PeterShor well, _emprunter_ is the commonly used verb for this, would you be out of some ingredient and knock at your neighbour's door to borrow something, then your would ask _Puis-je vous emprunter du lait ?_. I guess because _un prêt_ has that connotation of something you have to give back, while it is obvious you cannot give back an ingredient you've used in a receipt.

Comment: But then for something you would be able to give back, the two sounds right: _Puis-je t'emprunter ce vêtement ?_ / _Peux-tu me prêter ce vêtement ?_.